# ViewPager not updating textview font size instantly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `textview` inside `ViewPager`. I am using `PagerAdapter` to show the data. When I try to change the textview font size, it does not get updated because probably viewpager caches the recent views and reuses them again. So when I navigate to further pages, I can see the changes. How can I make the current page show the changes. Is there any way to destroy the cached views and draw the new page again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
pager.SetCurrentItem(curItem);
```

Comment: what is curItem in this case? Thanks. I have the same problem :D

Comment: curItem is the page index which you want to set as the current page.